# download file to a specific location with Response.BinaryWrite and Server.Mappath possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have varbinary data associated with a file in the DB. This is the code I'm using to download this file on clicking a link -

```
//a is my attachment object
var r = context.Response;
r.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + a.FileName);
r.Charset = "";
r.ContentType = a.MIME;   
r.BinaryWrite(a.Content.ToArray());
```

Currently, this file gets downloaded to the Downloads folder. Is there any way to create a new folder in the users system and have this file download there? I read that **server.mappath** can be used with r.WriteFile, but I'm not quite sure. Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Otherwise, people could maliciously write all manner of files into specific system directories. Once you send the file down to the user, the control is now out of your hands.

Comment: I triple that... Just imagine what would happen if a 3rd party had access to your file system!

Comment: @Tejs The folder where I need to download this file is the same as the one where my application will be installed, and I will be having access to this folder. So is there a way to specify the path?