# How to specify the path file to receive the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pechkin

I'm working with pechkin.dll to convert a webpage to a PDF file. I try to use "TransmitFile" set path, but it's not working.

This is my code and now that file is still store at C:\User\Username\download.

How do I specify the file in my project("~/convertFile")?

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=test.pdf; size={0}", pdf.Length));

Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: No, you can't specify a folder to save the file. It is either controlled by the user or the browser

Comment: you should go with silverlight or asp.net applet for achieving this task.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437872/download-file-to-a-specific-location-with-response-binarywrite-and-server-mappat

Comment: Now i have done in save file to specific path.Are you know if i want to open file and sent it to print, How to do that , i need to get another component to solve this function ? @Thangadurai; @Gopinath Koothaperumal;